# I am setting a component attribute in a setCallBack inside a helper class, and then the set value is lost once I'm outside setCallBack

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Here is the code my for my Helper class which is used to create a new case. I'm trying to set the Id of the newly created case to the attribute on the component itself. The 3 and 4 are showing undefined in the console but 1 and 2 are showing the ID properly. They are also displaying in the console in this order: 3,4,1,2

**Helper Class**

```
createCase: function(component, c) {
var action = component.get("c.saveCase");
action.setParams({
    "c": c
});

action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
        var id = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.caseId",id);
        console.log("1-" + component.get("v.caseId"));       
    }

    console.log("2-" + component.get("v.caseId"));
});

console.log("3-" + component.get("v.caseId"));
$A.enqueueAction(action);
console.log("4-" + component.get("v.caseId"));
```

**Component** code:

```
<aura:attribute name="caseId" type="String" />

<aura:attribute name="newCase" type="Case"
    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case', 
   'Subject': '',
   'Activity__c': '',
   'Reason': '',
   'Contact': '',
   'Description': '',
   'Origin' : '',
   'FOA__c' : '',
   'Project__c' : ''
   }"/>

    <div class="slds-form-element">
           <ui:button label="Submit" 
           class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
           labelClass="label"
           press="{!c.clickCreateCase}"
           />
     </div>
```

**Javascript Controller**

```
clickCreateCase: function(component, event, helper) {

var newCase = component.get("v.newCase");
console.log("Create case: " + JSON.stringify(newCase));
helper.createCase(component, newCase); 
}
```

**Apex Controller**

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveCase (Case c){
        upsert c;
        return String.ValueOf (c.Id);
    }
```

Comment: would you mind putting full code here because this looks weird

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I edited the code to clean it up and include other code.

Comment: can you post your apex controller? to see what saveCase method returns

Comment: How are you invoking your controller code ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I edited code. clickCreateCase is invoked when the button is pressed on the component.

Comment: couple of things 1 .Try replacing c in your parameter as more meaningful name like caseRecord 2. Also try moving all code to controller itself and see if that changes anything .3.Check all your brackets and ensure al of them has proper opening and closing .

Comment: I assume order of execution is due to the way lightning handles server response,"The solution to staying responsive while waiting is that server responses are handled asynchronously. "https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_server ,  I feel the OOE is the same reason why you get undefined because the client side controller executes 3 and 4 before the async request is completed, it does not have value back from the server side and hence throws an undefined

Comment: @Rao That makes sense to me but I am curious why then it is not 4,3,1,2,3,4 .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I am not expert at JS order of  execution but looking at the flow 3,4 ,1,2 made sense because the system does not execute 1,2 3,4 is completed while the async request is processing. What was your reasoning behind 4.3 than 3,4. My understanding of programming is top to bottom

Comment: Sorry i meant 3.4,1,2,3,4 .Because at some point the async will be processed and we should see a console.log output

Comment: Mohit, what Rao said is correct.Only the function passed as the callback will be called(similar to any other ajax request) when client gets the response from the server.So the order 3,4,1,2 is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This has basically been answered in the comments, but to sum up: This is a normal JavaScript behaviour not restricted to Lightning. Functions that will require time are executed in an **asynchronous and non-blocking** manner. The parent function takes a callback as a parameter but does not execute it; then it continues to execute subsequent lines in sequence. After an undetermined amount of time, when the results of the request come back, the callback is executed.

If you wanted to run some code only after the request is completed, you'd have to ensure that code executes within the callback. In JavaScript it used to be common to have callbacks inside of callbacks ad nauseam ("callback hell") for exactly this reason. There are many better strategies now including Promises which you can read up on. In Lightning another possible approach is to fire an event at the end of the callback, and then let the handler of that event take care of what needs to be done next.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've learned a lot about the inner workings of JavaScript/jQuery. I have a question in response to your explanation. Lets say that I have a callback in my initialization and only one callback. Is there any way to hold the page load so that the page isn't loading without data and then redrawn? I asked a question detailing this question with code: [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146976/using-datatables-in-a-lightning-componnent-question-around-asynchronous-behavior)

Comment: I think Lightning is not designed for you to be able to purposely hold up the page load. And frankly any rendering solution requiring jQuery is really not a good match for a Lightning Component. In any case it seems that what you want to delay is the execution of the DataTable function, not the loading of the resources themselves. In theory you could use Promises to ensure a piece of code is run only after *both* the init call back and the scripts are loaded.